# Why does app get stuck when installing on 64 bit 5s iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, installation

I have an enterprise app that I just upgraded to run on iOS 7. It installs fine on iPhones upgraded to iOS 7. However when I try to install on a new 5s (64 bit) device it "gets stuck". iTunes says it is "installing" and the icon on the device appears "grayed out". When I tap on the icon on the device it displays "installing" beneath the icon. It never completes the installation. I modified the build setting s to include "Standard architectures ( including 64-bit) (armv7, armv7s ...". I was then prompted to select the "Latest iOS (iOS7.0) which I did. I did a new archive and distribution. The .ipa file is .9 mg larger than it was previously, so I guess I've got a new build. Yet, the app still "hangs" on installing. I took a quick look and didn't see anything like this for iPhone 5 vs 5s. Once again the installation works quickly and completely on the iPhone 5. Anybody ran into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try deleting the app from the device first? Have you tried a power cycle? Have you ensure the provisioning profile includes the 5S device?

Comment: My provisioning file had not been updated - Sorry for the oversight - thank you for your answer